# create database table with a owner in my SQL

Tags: mysql, ddl

Can someone tell me what is the SQL command to create a table with specific owner?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to give some user access to the table owned by another user? If so, you need to use `GRANT privilege ON table_name TO user_name` or similar DCL command.

Comment: I want to create a new Database with a new owner.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such concept of database and / or table "owner" in mySQL.

Comment: When you say "owner", do you mean "database user"? If so, you probably need `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE USER` statements.

Answer (score 6):

There is no concept such as OWNER in mySQL for databases or for tables.

You will need to enforce security in the traditional way with granting very specific user privileges.

for e.g. for inserts: `GRANT INSERT ON database.* TO 'username'@'hostname' ;`